# How would I extract the <div> data from this section?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to setup a discord.js bot that pulls div data based on a class

```
            <template v-if="activeWindow">
            <div class="trn-card mb0">
                <div class="trn-card__header">
                    <h3 class="trn-card__header-title">Session {{ activeWindowNumber }}</h3>
                    <span class="trn-card__header-subline">{{ activeWindow.matchesPlayed }} Matches</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trn-card__content">
                    <div class="fn-event-team__stats mb8">
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Rank</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">#{{ activeWindow.rank }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Points Earned</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">{{ activeWindow.pointsEarned }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Eliminations</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">{{ activeWindow.kills }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fn-event-team__stats fn-event-team__stats--small">
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">K/D</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">#{{ activeWindow.kdRatio }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Avg. Kills</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">#{{ activeWindow.avgKills }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Avg. Placement</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">#{{ activeWindow.avgPlacement }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Avg. Points</div>
                            <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">#{{ activeWindow.avgPoints }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I'm trying to pull the value from the divs with the class "fn-event-team__stat_value, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out by using the javascript method as follow :

```
var arr = [];
$("#Button").click(function() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('.fn-event-team__stat_value');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        arr.push(items[i].value);
});
console.log(arr) ; //you will get all the values of divs .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` and `map` which will return an array. `innerHTML` will give the content of the `div`. `trim` is used to remove any white space.

```js
let vals = [...document.querySelectorAll('.fn-event-team__stat-value')].map(item => item.innerHTML.trim());
console.log(vals)
```

```html
<div class="trn-card__content">
  <div class="fn-event-team__stats mb8">
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Rank</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Points Earned</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Eliminations</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fn-event-team__stats fn-event-team__stats--small">
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">K/D</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Avg. Kills</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Avg. Placement</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fn-event-team__stat">
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-name">Avg. Points</div>
      <div class="fn-event-team__stat-value">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```